# Свой UrlRule yii2

Tags: yii2, маршрутизация

Я столкнулся с проблемой в yii2, когда нужно сделать url с множеством параметрами, при этом каждый из них может отсутствовать.
Например:

> site.com/index/param1/value1/param2/valu2/param3/value3/param4/value4

либо

> site.com/param2/value2/param4/value4

(всего может быть 4 параметра и у них фиксированное название).
Самая трудность, что я не смог найти хорошей документации и примеров.

```
public function createUrl($manager, $route, $params)
    {
        if ($route === 'site/index') {
            if (isset($params['ship']) OR isset($params['map']) OR isset($params['gamemode']) OR isset($params['version'])) {
                return (isset($params['ship'])) ? $params['ship'] . '/' : ''
                . (isset($params['map'])) ? $params['map'] . '/' : ''
                . (isset($params['gamemode'])) ? $params['gamemode'] . '/' : ''
                . (isset($params['version'])) ? $params['version'] . '/' : '';
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function parseRequest($manager, $request)
    {
        $pathInfo = $request->getPathInfo();
        if (preg_match('%^(\w+)(/(\w+))?$%', $pathInfo, $matches)) {

        }
        return false;
    }
```

Также мне не понятно, что нужно делать в parseRequest и откуда там берётся $params.